# program to convert sheet1(excel) into standard sheet2(excel)

Tags: php, c++, excel

Is it possible to write a program that change the order of columns in *sheet1(excel)* based on a table in standard *sheet2(excel)*?

Sheet1 have the same header of each column as sheet2  but the position of columns is not same and also it is possible that some more columns are present in sheet(1). Finally I have to store the standard sheet into the database.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow .. please take some time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) - particularly the section on [What questions can I ask here ?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't be possible

Comment: will u give me some suggestions

Comment: each time i receive the sheet some more columns are added each time. I personally map each of the columns manually as per the standard sheet then if some thing new, then create columns in the database and run the scripts to store the data in database. If someone guide me some way to get rid of this manual process i m very thankful.

Comment: What's going on here Krishnachandra Sharma opened a bounty on this question and answered it?

Comment: Expecting some more good answers. user1517413 accepted it, thats good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it possible to change the order of columns.

Steps:

1. Change the excel sheet format file to `csv` file.
2. Write a `PHP` code to arrange the random columns as per the standard sheet.
3. Write a code to enter this data into the database. Each time you receive the new column append it at the last of the standard column.
4. Make the respective change in the `PHP` code for the same.

Answer (score -2):

This is probably a dumb answer, but back in the day I used VB code inside of Excel workbooks to manipulate data including culling information from one worksheet and creating another based on contents.

Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx for more information.